# Outputting spliced version of input

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char name[256];
  cout << "Enter your name: ";
  cin.getline (name,256);

  for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {  
    cout << name[i];

    if (name[i] == '\n')
      break;
  }

  cout << endl;
  return(0);
}
```

Enter your name: My name is Sean

once I do that it outputs "My name is Sean" but then a bunch of nonsense crazy symbols after that.

How come it doesn't stop after 'n' in Sean? Since there's a '\n' character there. Or at least I would think.

All, I want is to output every character in name one symbol at a time, and stop when it gets to the end of the line so that it doesn't have to go to 256 when the array is actually much smaller

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Tag this homework please if it is.

Answer (score 3):

`cin.getline` reads the newline (or whatever you specify as the delmiter) out of the input buffer, but does NOT include it in the string that's produced, so you're reading past the end of the data that was read until you encounter the next byte that happens to contain the value that corresponds to a new-line (typically 10).

It's a lot easier to just write it all together: `cout << name;`

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> Characters are extracted until either
>   (n - 1) characters have been extracted
>   or the delimiting character is found
>   (which is delim if this parameter is
>   specified, or '\n' otherwise). The
>   extraction also stops if the end of
>   file is reached in the input sequence
>   or if an error occurs during the input
>   operation.
>
> **If the delimiter is found, it is
>   extracted and discarded**, i.e. it is
>   not stored and the next input
>   operation will begin after it. If you
>   don't want this character to be
>   extracted, you can use member get
>   instead.